# LZO-Compress and Indexing Files on HDFS In-place?

Tags: hadoop, lzo

Normally I'll do the following to use LZO:

1. Use lzop command to compress the data file on local disk.
2. Put it into HDFS.
3. Use distributed lzo indexer the generate the .index files.

I'm wondering is there a way to compress and index the raw files on HDFS in-place at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Yep you can:

In your core-site.xml on the client and server append com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec to the comma-separated list of codecs:

```
<property>
  <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,
    org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DeflateCodec,
    org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec</value>
</property>
```

Edit mapred-site.xml file on the JobTracker host machine:

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>  

<property>     
   <name>mapred.map.output.compression.codec</name>
   <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec</value>   
</property> 

<property>     
   <name>mapred.output.compression.type</name>        
   <value>BLOCK</value>
</property>
```